# ¿Como convertir un resultado NaN a número?

Tags: javascript, html, desarrollo

Amigos espero que se encuentren muy bien.

Estoy realizando un ejercicio para manejo de errores pero el resultado en consola de la suma que necesito operar me sale como un valor NaN.

¿Como podría hacer para que en consola no me aparezca NaN si no que me aparezca el resultado de la suma?

Aquí mi código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Manejo de errores en programación asíncrona</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function sumarNumero(a, b){
            setTimeout(function(){
                console.log(a+b);
            }, 1000);
        }
        sumarNumero(Number(1+2));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Tu error está en la llamada a la función: `sumarNumero(Number(1+2));` le estarías pasando tan sólo un parámetro consistente en la suma de `1+2`, cuando la función espera **dos parámetros**.

Debes pasarle dos parámetros.

Y, si quieres evitar los `NaN` dentro de la función puedes hacer una verificación de tipos, usando una combinación [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) con [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof). Es importante también forzar una conversión del valor a numérico para los casos en que los parémetros sean cadenas. Esto lo puedes hacer poniendo el operador `+` delante del valor resultante en la parte izquierda del ternario, por eso he puesto `+a` y `+b`.

La función quedaría de este modo, luego probaremos con varios tipos de valores:

```js
function sumarNumero(a, b) {
  a = !isNaN(a) && typeof a !== 'boolean' ? +a : 0;
  b = !isNaN(b) && typeof b !== 'boolean' ? +b : 0;
  console.log(a+b);
}
sumarNumero(1, '0');
sumarNumero(undefined, 2);
sumarNumero(3, 'a');
sumarNumero(4, false);
sumarNumero(7, '-2');
sumarNumero(6, null);
sumarNumero(true, 7);
sumarNumero(" 2", 6);
sumarNumero(4.5, 4.5);

sumarNumero(true, true);
sumarNumero(false, false);
sumarNumero(false, true);
sumarNumero(undefined, undefined);
sumarNumero(undefined, null);
sumarNumero(false, undefined);
sumarNumero(undefined, true);
```

Comment: Hay que tener cuidado con la forma en que usas la salida de consola. Esto: `a|0+b|0` no será tratado como lo que quieres: `(a|0) + (b|0)`. Basta probar pasando dos valores numéricos a tu actual función y ver que el resultado no es el esperado, puedes probar con `sumarNumero(1, 1)`. Por otro lado, cuidado con usar el operador *bitwise OR* a la ligera, dices que *si quieres evitar los `NaN` dentro de la función puedes forzar que los no numéricos sean `0` usando el operador `|`*, pero un booleano no es numérico por definición y si yo uso: `sumarNumero(1, true)` el resultado (`true | 0`) es `1`...

Comment: Entonces, si bien este caso es el único particular en que la premisa falla, yo usaría el mismo lenguaje para determinan la *numerabilidad* de un valor. Yo optaría por el viejo y confiable `typeof` seguido del método antiguo: [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN). Te lo dejo allí para que corrijas tu respuesta. Saludos

Comment: @ElTroll tienes toda la razón. He modificado la respuesta haciendo una verificación del tipo booleano y usando `isNaN`.